# Python: Trying to program a variant of connect four: Winning condition doesn't stop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix, infinite-loop

I have been trying to program a variant of connect four for my programming class.  The board is 6x8 in size. In the variant I'm trying to program, the winning condition is to essentially build an L.

This means any construction of the form
X
X
X X
is a winning condition.
I have been trying to make a function that checks every single column for the same symbol consecutively to build a pair. And a function to do the same for every row. With these two functions I would then check if 2 pairs are consecutive, because no matter how you combine a vertical and horizontal pair, it will always build an 'L'.

To make a clear board I'm using

```
def ClearBoardSingle():
    global Board
    Board = [['0' for i in range(8)] for i in range(6)]
    BoardPrint()
    PlayerMoveSingle()
```

And for my interface I'm using

```
def BoardPrint():
    global Board
    global GameMoves
    global PlayerTurn
    global Player1Symbol
    global Player2Symbol
    print('\n\nMoves done: ' + str(GameMoves))
    print('To Restart: R | To Quit: Q')
    print('Valid choices: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8')
    if PlayerTurn == 0:
        print('It\'s ' +str(Player1Symbol) + '\'s Turn')
    if PlayerTurn == 1:
        print('It\'s ' +str(Player2Symbol) + '\'s Turn')
    print(Board[0])
    print(Board[1])
    print(Board[2])
    print(Board[3])
    print(Board[4])
    print(Board[5])
```

I already figured out how to change Variables inside the Board, and I'm pretty much done. The only thing I don't know how to implement is the winning condition. I tried this function for the Rows:

```
def VerticalList(Column):
    global Board
    global Choice
    global Row0
    Column = int(Column)
    Choice = int(Choice)
    print(Column,' C')
    while Column > 0:
        for Board[Column][Choice] in range(Column):
            Row0.append(Board[Column][Choice])
            if Column ==6 or Column == -1:
                break
            else:
                VerticalList(Column-1)
        if Column ==0:
            break
        else:
            continue
    if Column == 0:
        Column += 1
        while Column < 5:
            Column +=1
            if Row0[Column] == Row0[Column-1]:
                print('Pair')
            else:
                print('No Pair')
                pass
    else:
        pass
```

But it enters an endless Loop.
I have no ideas anymore on how to implement the winning condition. I'd appreciate any kind of help or ideas. If you want me to post the whole code or other kinds of snippets, ask for them.

Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: Wow, sounds just like a CS101 problem I had too, back when memory was measured in MB

Comment: is your code formatted properly? possibly just cut-n-paste error getting it into SO? indentation of your code affect variable scope.

Comment: I programmed the winning condition in another file, so I dont accidentally mess up my game code. I tried My "Game" out and it works properly, but since I have no winning condition implemented yet, the game only ends when all fields are filled (48 in this case).

Comment: @No7ExQ Please format your code variable/function names ([pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Oh yeah I did that yesterday, thnk you for the reminder tho (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool problem, below looks like a lot of code, but it's not really. I haven't checked this extensively, so I'm not confident that it doesn't find false positives, but it seems to find L's that it should be finding. The main thing I did was use `itertools.combinations` to take all 4-sized groups of the positions of X's and then check if they looked like patterns I was expecting for L's. In `check_four_group` I look at the differences within the row and columns.

```
from itertools import combinations
def disp_board(board): 
    for row in board: 
        print(row)

def check_winning(board): 
    winning = False 

    #Find all row,col positions of the X's
    x_poses = [(i,j) for i in range(6) for j in range(8) if board[i][j] == 'X'] 

    #Loop through every combination of four X's since it takes four to make the 'L'
    for group in combinations(x_poses,4):
        if(check_four_group(group)): 
            winning = True 
            break 
    return winning

def check_four_group(group): 
    rows,cols = zip(*[(r,c) for r,c in group]) 
    row_diffs = [rows[i+1]-rows[i] for i in range(len(rows)-1)] 
    col_diffs = [cols[i+1]-cols[i] for i in range(len(cols)-1)] 

    #Uncomment this to print the row and col diffs
    #print(row_diffs) 
    #print(col_diffs)

    # Finds:
    #  X
    #  X
    #  X X
    if row_diffs == [1,1,0] and col_diffs == [0,0,1]:
        return True

    # Finds:
    #    X
    #    X
    #  X X
    elif row_diffs == [1,1,0] and col_diffs == [0,-1,1]:
        return True

    # Finds:
    #  X X
    #    X
    #    X
    elif row_diffs == [0,1,1] and col_diffs == [1,0,0]:
        return True

    # Finds:
    #  X X
    #  X
    #  X
    elif row_diffs == [0,1,1] and col_diffs == [1,-1,0]:
        return True

    # Otherwise it's not there at all (not thinking about horizontal L's but could add that)
    else:
        return False

#Test case 1
def test_case_1():
    board = [['0' for i in range(8)] for i in range(6)] 
    board[2][1] = 'X' 
    board[2][2] = 'X' 
    board[3][1] = 'X' 
    board[4][1] = 'X' 
    return board

#Test case 2
def test_case_2():
    board = [['0' for i in range(8)] for i in range(6)] 
    board[2][1] = 'X' 
    board[2][0] = 'X' 
    board[3][1] = 'X' 
    board[4][1] = 'X' 
    return board

#Test case 3
def test_case_3():
    board = [['0' for i in range(8)] for i in range(6)] 
    board[1][0] = 'X' 
    board[2][0] = 'X' 
    board[3][0] = 'X' 
    board[3][1] = 'X' 
    return board

#Test case 4
def test_case_4():
    board = [['0' for i in range(8)] for i in range(6)] 
    board[1][2] = 'X' 
    board[2][2] = 'X' 
    board[3][2] = 'X' 
    board[3][1] = 'X'
    return board

##################
#Start of program#
##################
board = test_case_1()
#board = test_case_2()
#board = test_case_3()
#board = test_case_4()

disp_board(board)
if check_winning(board): 
    print('Victory')
else: 
    print('Keep playing')
```

Comment: Ok Thank you very much, Ill try to first of all understand :P and then implement this into my game. I'll keep you updated if anything is wrong.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to give you an update, but I thought I should understand the code before using it (: So after understanding it I added winning options for the horizontal L's and then added everything into my gamecode. It works!! So you sir just kept me from hours of despair and a major headache.

Comment: awesome! nice job adding the horizontal L's!